# Google Analytics - Handling Hostname changes in the filters

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I have my Google Analytics account set up for my web application, lets say my application name is Appstore.com

I have different environments for my application Appstore-dev.com , Appstore-qa.com, Appstore-uat.com and the production Appstore.com.

To capture the traffic of all these sites i created a single property in the property settings under the Default url i have given my production url Appstore.com.

For the same property i created 4 different views for Dev, QA, UAT and Production, Now for each View i have added a filter which says 'Include Only' 'Traffic to the host name' 'that are equal to' and the corresponding url of that View.

Now my application URL's are going to change, and i want to existing data in the views to be as it is and from now onwards capture the data from the new url, lets say new URL's are Newappstore-dev.com , Newappstore-qa.com, Newappstore-uat.com and the production Newappstore.com.

If i just change the host name in the filters of each view will that be a right approach ?

Note : The source code or my application is not going to change in any way only the application URL's are going to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you just need to change the filter with the new hostnames and from that moment Analytics will collect only the data coming from those hostnames.